# Git Branches & Environments Development Process for CI/CD

Tags: git, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, agile

I have a "development process" question I was hoping to get some experiences and opinions.

I'm working with a company that has the typical `dev`, `staging` and `production` env's. There are a dozen different git repos and a branch correlating to each environment for CI/CD.

There are ~15 devs working on tasks across branches each day.
`dev` env is used for QA, `staging` is a production ready deployable env at any time. This is all normal business, no issues on the environments.

Here's where it gets tricky, the direction and process of merging code with git from one env to another:

`dev` doesn't get merged directly into `staging`, ever. The current process is to use cherry-pick to get code from `dev` -> `staging` so that there isn't anything from another developer that's in the QA step in the `dev` env being merged into `staging` that shouldn't be.

This is a really messy/risky process, IMO, because if you [developer] are cherry-picking your commits from `dev` into `staging` then you could miss commits and you could imagine the headache that would arise from that!

---

Is there a better process we could employ with our env modeling?

Comment: Some additional context will help: What is the flow from staging to the production branch? How is the dev branch populated- is dev a throwaway branch that is re-created periodically from the production branch, or is production merged back into dev later? Are feature branches merged into dev with PRs? Could those same branches be merged into staging instead of cherry-picking each of the commits?

Comment: This is opinion-based so you're going to get a lot of different answers, but for me I prefer the version of github-flow described here: http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html. If you google github-flow today, you'll find a nice interactive version here: https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/ but they're basically the same thing. The blog post is more descriptive for each step, and explains some benefits/complaints about git-flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand this is opinion based and may not be the *correct* answer for everyone/situation. (Thank you to @adam for the mention of git-flow.)

**The environments:**

- production
- staging
- dev

**Staging** is intended to be a stable release/environment that can be deployed to master at any point in time. **Dev** is the QA and *dev* environment before **staging**.

**Git branches:**

- master (production)
- staging
- dev
- feature/[name] bugfix/[name] etc. (follows git-flow pattern)

The development process/flow:
A developer is assigned a ticket. The developer checks out a new feature/bugfix branch from `staging` branch. The developer does hiser work on the feature/bugfix branch and MR/PR's into `dev` branch so it can be QA'd in the **dev** environment. Once the ticket passes QA, the developer opens an MR/PR with `feature/bugfix` -> `staging`. After the `feature/bugfix` is merged into `staging` it can be discarded.

Housekeeping needs to be kept up to date on the branches, regularly - most importantly, `dev` needs to rebase on `staging` often to keep the QA environment healthy and up to date.